# Spring Batch Job Parameters in Item Reader

Tags: spring-batch

My parameter (`workingDirectory`) is always `null` and I do not understand why?
I am using the job launcher to kick off the job.
I see the job parameter in the database but it is not getting injected into my reader.

This is my reader.

```
@Component("customerReader")
@StepScope
public class CustomReader implements ItemReader<Customer> {

  @Value("#{jobParameters['workingDirectory']}")
  protected String workingDirectory;

  private BufferedReader reader;
  protected ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  private int fileIdx = 1;


  @Override
  public Customer read() throws IOException {

    if(reader == null) {
      reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(workingDirectory + "output1.json")));
    }
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
      try {
        fileIdx++;
        reader = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(new File(workingDirectory + "output" + fileIdx + ".json")));
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        return null;
      }
      line = reader.readLine();
    }
    return objectMapper.readValue(line, Customer.class);
  }
}
```

I am launching by calling:

```
JobParameters p = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("workingDirectory", workingDirectory).toJobParameters();
JobExecution e = jobLauncher.run(
            recordGenerator.getJob(file, "/Users/abc/data/"), p);
```

Comment: I think this is not spring batch's problem, but spring configuration. I see that `Value("#{jobParameters['workingDirectory']}")` is null, so maybe spring can't inject this property into your bean. Please check your spring context's initialization and read about `@Value` javadoc